# When I echo a Zend_Db query it contains 'ON Array', why?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

Sql Query:

```
SELECT test.* FROM test JOIN test_shares
WHERE test.test_id = test_shares.test_id 
AND test_shares.email_address = '$email' 
AND test.url is NOT NULL ORDER BY title ASC;
```

Rewritten as `Zend_Db_Select` statement.

```
$select = $db->select ()
    ->from ( 'test', 'test.*' )
    ->join ( 'test_shares', array () )
    ->where ( 'test.test_id = test_shares.test_id')
    ->where ( 'test_shares.email_address = ?',  '$email')
    ->where ( 'test.url is NOT NULL')
    ->order ( 'title' );
echo $select;
```

Output:

```
SELECT test.* FROM test JOIN test_shares ON Array 
WHERE test.test_id = test_shares.test_id 
AND test_shares.email_address = '$email' 
AND test.url is NOT NULL ORDER BY title ASC
```

Please suggest why this 'ON Array' is showing.

Comment: Obviously it is because of your ->join('movie_shares', array() ). What happens if you put null there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$select = $db   ->select ()
    ->from ( 'movie', 'movie.*' )
    ->join(array('movie_shares'),  'movie.movie_id = movie_shares.movie_id');    
    ->where ( 'movie_shares.email_address = ?',  '$email')
    ->where ( 'movie.url is NOT NULL')
    ->order ( 'title' );
echo $select;
```

You're supplying an array where a string is expected for the ON clause, so PHP literally prints `array()` instead of the string.